# Import data from one sheet to “only one cell” in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, textjoin

I have 3 columns with variable data below them. I need to import all 3 columns in this format "`A <> B -- (C)`" to one singular cell. I have not the slightest clue how to do this. I found a question that was similar to this but I can't make heads or tales of the formula.

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10),QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTRANGE("SpreadsheetID",A2:C100)),,2e6))
```

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pTDQgtwTt6RlU2TRVAc_b2Pd8KHMgsAt-dOsMB0EPh8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A2:C<>"", A2:C, )),,999^99))))
```

or this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A2:A<>"", A2:A&" <> "&B2:B&" -- ("&C2:C&")", )),,999^99))))
```

[image: 0]